# Is there any tool which convert book to html format with Table of Contents?

Tags: html, ebooks

I have a small pdf ebook and I want to publish this book in my blog with the table of contents. I am looking for a tool that to divide the book into sections and create Table of Contents in HTML format as the O'Reilly does.
[image]

I have tried pandoc pdf to HTML. But the results were terrible.

Note: Please warn me if this image against the terms of use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have tried [Calibre](https://calibre-ebook.com/download); it has created smooth HTML TOC and HTML content give it a try if you have this problem. It pulls all sections and chapters and creates an organized Table of Contents like this:

[image]

You can also add style with CSS and give it a nice looking.

Note: I mean structural design, not the whole document is smoothly converted. You must made manual changes on elements with bad structured pdf books.

Comment: Please provide a link.

Comment: You can download calibre with using this link.https://calibre-ebook.com/download or do you want to see results?

Comment: Nice question, but the answer requires more work. Please edit your answer to add that link. Please also include the steps required, and add a screenshot of the result. Thanks! :-)

Comment: Also, please read http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/356/what-is-required-for-an-answer-to-be-high-quality Cheers!

Comment: Answer now worth an up vote!